# Optimization using streams

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering what happens with left out data filtered through stream.where. is it kept in memory? Or can I use it a lot when fetching data without worrying about optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can don't worry about optimization,
because stream just sends data to listeners and doesn't store any data in memory.

> Streams do not store data